Issue with Decimal Precision in Flow-Generated Records
I have a flow that calls an apex class and then creates some records when an Opportunity is updated to Closed Won.
The new records are created under the Object A custom object.
Somehow, the Amount field (custom field, data type: Currency, accepting 2 decimals - 16, 2) is partially being filled: it receives a number with no decimals.
The calculation in the apex class of the Amount field is as follows: Total_Amount__c / Subscription__c
Total_Amount__c is a formula returning a Currency (18, 0 - so no decimals)
Subscription__c is a Number field (18, 0 - so no decimals)
Here is the code:
public with sharing class Financial_Projection_Class {
@InvocableMethod(label='Financial Projection Class' description='Generates Financial Projection Class records based on a number and a starting date.')
public static List<List<Financial_Projection__c>> generateProjections(List<RequestWrapper> requests) {
    // List to hold all projections
    List<Financial_Projection__c> projections = new List<Financial_Projection__c>();

    for (RequestWrapper request : requests) {
        Date startDate = request.startDate;
        Integer numberOfRecords = request.numberOfRecords;
        String OpportunityID = request.OpportunityID;
        String ProductID = request.ProductID;
        Integer SubscriptionTermMonth = request.SubscriptionTermMonth;
        Date ProductStartDate = request.ProductStartDate;
        Integer Amount = request.Amount;

        for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfRecords; i++) {
            // Increment the date by i months
            Date recordDate = startDate.addMonths(i);

            // Create a new Financial_Projection__c record
                Financial_Projection__c projection = new Financial_Projection__c();
            // Inserts in the Name field the following value: Year/Month
                projection.Name = recordDate.year() + '/' + 
                  (recordDate.month() >= 10 ? 
                   String.valueOf(recordDate.month()) : 
                   '0' + String.valueOf(recordDate.month()));
            
            projection.Product__c = ProductID;
            projection.Subscription_Terms_Month__c = SubscriptionTermMonth;
            projection.Opportunity__c = OpportunityID;
            projection.Product_Start_Date__c = ProductStartDate;
            
            // inserts in the Amount field the following value: Amount / SubscriptionTermMonth
            projection.Amount__c = (Amount / SubscriptionTermMonth);
            
            // inserts in the Product End Date field the following value: (Product Start Date + Subscription Terms Month) - 1 day
            projection.Product_End_Date__c = ProductStartDate.addMonths(SubscriptionTermMonth).addDays(-1); 
            projections.add(projection);
            
            
        }
    }

    // Return as a list of lists to match InvocableMethod return type
    return new List<List<Financial_Projection__c>> { projections };
}

// Wrapper class to define inputs for the Invocable Method
public class RequestWrapper {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Number of Records' required=true description='The number of records to generate.')
    public Integer numberOfRecords;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Start Date' required=true description='The starting date for generating projections.')
    public Date startDate;
    
    @InvocableVariable(label='OpportunityID' required=true description='Opportunity ID of the Triggering Opportunity in the Flow')
    public String OpportunityID;
    
    @InvocableVariable(label='ProductID' required=true description='Product ID of the Opportunity Product in the first Loop')
    public String ProductID;
    
    @InvocableVariable(label='SubscriptionTermMonth' required=true description='SubscriptionTermMonth of the Opportunity Product in the first Loop')
    public Integer SubscriptionTermMonth;
    
    @InvocableVariable(label='ProductStartDate' required=true description='ProductStartDate of the Opportunity Product in the first Loop')
    public Date ProductStartDate;
    
    @InvocableVariable(label='Amount' required=true description='Product Total Cost of the Opportunity Product in the first Loop')
    public Integer Amount;
}

}
Here is my problematic scenario:
If Total_Amount__c = $500,000 and Subscription__c = 12
I was expecting the Amount field to be filled with $41,666.66, but the Amount field is receiving $41,666.00.
Any ideas on why it is happening please?
Thanks a lot!

In your wrapper both Amount and SubscriptionTermMonth are Integer and in Java (Apex is based upon Java) and in many other strongly typed languages, if the type of both operands is integer (or long), the result will be an integer (or long). JLS

If the promoted type is int or long, then integer arithmetic is performed.

Indeed Apex documentation states (emphasis mine):

Division operator. Divides x, an Integer or Double, by y, another Integer or Double. If a double is used, the result is a Double.

Only if at least one of the operands is a Double, the result will be a Double, so to fix this, just cast at least one of the operand to Double.
From anonymous window you could try:
Integer a = 10;
Integer b = 3;
System.debug(a / b); // 3
System.debug((Double) a / b); // 3.3333333333333335

So you just have to change this line
projection.Amount__c = (Amount / SubscriptionTermMonth);

to
projection.Amount__c = ((Double) Amount / SubscriptionTermMonth);

By the way, when working with Decimal, you could rely on divide(divisor, scale) to get the desired output
